# Cannot see files under 744 permission in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, public-folders

I have a MediaWiki installation running under Apache. I've found a problem with file access and after some research, I've found the problem is file system permissions.

If my uploads directory has the permission 755 everything works ok, but if I change the permissions to 744, then I'm unable to access to this file folder (Forbidden).

What's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you have to have execute permission or higher (5) on a directory to list the contents of that directory.  You can access files in a directory if you have read permission (4) but you have to know the name of the file because you can't list the contents of the directory.

So, the user you are using to access the directory is not the user who owns the directory (because then the '7' permission would apply.  Thus to fix this either use mode 755 on the directory, or make it so that the same user owns the directory and accesses it.  Or of course, always know the exact filename you are trying to access in the directory, then the 4 permission is sufficient.